# OperationalError at /admin/app/question/ no such table: app_question (django)

Tags: django

Im new to this and Im tryna make a q&a type of app, I was just starting then when I went to admin/ to try it out I got

```
OperationalError at /admin/app/question/
no such table: app_question

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app/question/

Django Version: 4.0.1
Python Version: 3.10.1
Installed Applications:
['app',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/app/question/
Exception Value: no such table: app_question
```

here is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from users.models import CustomUser

# This is the question model
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.TextField()
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# This is the answer model

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail
```

I'd appreciate if its explained in a beginner friendly manner, thank you!

Comment: did you ever delete your migrations dir manually?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) is the documentation. You should

> run migrate again to create those model tables in your database:

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but when I migrated it, it said, "No migrations to apply."

Comment: In that case, you should make migraitons manually. As the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) says:  
  > python manage.py makemigrations polls. In your case, it should be python manage.py makemigrations app

Comment: By the way, it's not a good idea to put all your django app in a single app directory. Maybe you should follow the documentation, and just create a polls directory.